# Spring XD Container Logs on Yarn

Tags: spring-xd

My environment is the following:

Spring XD 1.2.1-RELEASE
HDP 2.2.4.2

I have Spring XD running on Yarn and I noticed that every time I submit the Spring XD application to the cluster, the container logs are created dynamically based on a directory prefix, yarn application id, and yarn container id.  This tends to make them a little hard to find, especially if you want to consolidate logs.  Is there a way  control where these logs are stored so that I can put together some sort of log consolidation.  Using Spring XD for this would be great, but I'm not sure how I would be able to tell Spring XD where they are located since the yarn application id and container id are generated dynamically at deploy time by HDP.

-Frank

Answer (score 0):

Frank, I hope I understood you correctly when I say "yarn logs -applicationId $appid" is what you are looking for.  When the application completes all container logs including STDERR and STDOUT from your code is consolidated.

See details on log aggregation and retention here
http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/